# How can i remove these "|" From my pagination

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, pagination

The pagination creates | after each number, i want to remove it but i cant find where and how.

Can someone help me?

ex:

<< <1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9> >>

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I'm sure someone can, but we can't tell you where or how without some code, or at least knowing how it's being done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation for CakePHP’s paginator](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/paginator.html#creating-page-number-links) helper, you’ll see there’s an option for that:

> `separator` Separator content defaults to |

Just set it to an empty string or `null` instead when adding page numbers to your view:

```
<?php
echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array(
    'separator' => ''
));
```

Comment: No problem. You can tweak pretty mcuh any/all of the HTML the Paginator helper generates with the options in the docs.